# How to reduce sample size in predictive model?

Tags: regression, sample-size, dimensionality-reduction

I am working on a regression model, which purpose is solely to predict new data. My training dataset contains around 200 measurements and with a best subset regression i was able to find good models for prediction.

Now, as gaining new data is extremely time consuming and expensive, i like to reduce the necessary sample size as much as possible, while keeping the predictive power as high as possible. This is, because I intent to use the model for similar use cases, where there is far less data available.

How would you approach this task?

Thanks!

Comment: IF you are only interested in predictive accuracy then you can use a test set or Cross Validation to determine a good threshold above which the accuracy doesn't improve much.

Comment: You think doing a k-fold CV where k is zero to n? I thought about iteratively removing a random data point and keeping the k constant until no data is left in the dataset.

Comment: Basically you create random subsamples of your data in a certain range, say 30 samples, 40, 50 and so on. For each sample you do say 5-CV. In the end you can plot the results and select a good threshold.

Comment: Ah okay, sounds like a good idea!
If different regression model result in quite similar results, are there any differences to expected with your method if I run then for multiple models?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I have multiple regression models. I am wondering If my choice for this calculation is having an impact.

Another thing: Should I do the CV with the subsamples? Wouldn't it be better to use the whole dataset for validation? In CV the subsamples are divided in test and trainingsset. So a subsample with 10 datapoint is going to have just a couple of datapoint for validation

Comment: If you have enough data points left for a test set then using a test set is better, when you are using all or close to all data points then you would switch to CV. I don't understand what you mean by your choice having an impact? Your choice of what having an impact on what?